# ¿Definir directorio inicial en input type File?

Tags: html, html5

Es posible definir la carpeta inicial que se muestra al pulsar en un componente `<input type="file">`??, es decir, yo coloco la etiqueta:

```html
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" accept=".png" multiple required/>
```

y esta me ejecuta el explorador de archivos bien, pero digamos, necesito que en lugar de que se abra en el escritorio (que así abre por default) me abra en Mis Documentos.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Adicional si alguien sabe como eliminar la opción `Todos los archivos` que aparece en filtro, y que solo aparezca la opción o las opciones que yo elegí en el `accept`

Answer (score 2):

Para filtrar por tipo de archivo, en este caso PNG, debieras poner el `content-type`, en este caso `image/png`:

```html
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" accept=".png,image/png" multiple required/>
```

De todas maneras ese filtro es sólo para comodidad del usuario. Él mismo puede cambiar el filtro para ver todos los archivos, y luego subir cualquier cosa. Incluso, aunque pudieras obligarlo a mantener ese filtro, él podría renombrar un archivo cualquiera y subirlo. Esto significa que si de verdad quieres recibir sólo PNG, tendrás que detectar el `MIME type` del lado del servidor.

Respecto a forzar la carpeta donde se abre el diálogo, **eso no es posible** con HTML. Primero es impráctico, la ruta absoluta de cualquier cosa depende del sistema operativo. Segundo, sería un riesgo de seguridad para cualquiera que operase con tal formulario.

Comment: Umm vale, entiendo lo de la ruta; respecto a lo del `MIME type` estoy manejando asp.net como seria eso, la verdad nunca lo he hecho, por ahora, de la misma manera lo que hago es siempre validar el formato del archivo para subirlo.